# annotate r squared to ggplot by using facet_wrap

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, regression, facet-wrap

I just joined the community and looking forward to get some help for the data analysis for my master thesis.

At the moment I have the following problem:

I plotted 42 varieties with ggplot by using facet_wrap:

```
`ggplot(sumfvvar,aes(x=TemperaturCmean,y=Fv.Fm,col=treatment))+
  geom_point(shape=1,size=1)+
  geom_smooth(method=lm)+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")+
  facet_wrap(.~Variety)`
```

That works very well, but I would like to annotate the r squared values for the regression lines. I have two treatments and 42 varieties, therefore 84 regression lines. 
Are there any possibilties to calculate all r squared values and integrate them into the ggplot? I found allready the function

```
ggplotRegression <- function (fit) {

require(ggplot2)

ggplot(fit$model, aes_string(x = names(fit$model)[2], y = names(fit$model)[1])) + 
geom_point() +
stat_smooth(method = "lm") +
labs(title = paste("Adj R2 = ",signif(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, 5),
                   "Intercept =",signif(fit$coef[[1]],5 ),
                   " Slope =",signif(fit$coef[[2]], 5),
                   " P =",signif(summary(fit)$coef[2,4], 5)))
}
```

but that works just for one variety and one treatment. Could be a loop for the lm() function an option?

Comment: It's easy with the `ggpmisc` package. Take a look at the vignette or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839940/coefficients-per-facet-with-output-type-numeric-in-ggpmiscstat-poly-eq/58841768#58841768).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply different labels to different facet, unless you add another r^2 column to your data.. One way is to use geom_text, but you need to calculate the stats you need first. Below I show an example with iris, and for your case, just change Species for Variety, and so on

```
library(tidyverse)
# simulate data for 2 treatments
# d2 is just shifted up from d1
d1 <- data.frame(iris,Treatment="A")
d2 <- data.frame(iris,Treatment="B") %>% 
mutate(Sepal.Length=Sepal.Length+rnorm(nrow(iris),1,0.5))
# combine datasets
DF <- rbind(d1,d2) %>% rename(Variety = Species)

# plot like you did
# note I use "free" scales, if scales very different between Species
# your facet plots will be squished
g <- ggplot(DF,aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Sepal.Length,col=Treatment))+
  geom_point(shape=1,size=1)+
  geom_smooth(method=lm)+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")+
  facet_wrap(.~Variety,scales="free")

# rsq function
RSQ = function(y,x){signif(summary(lm(y ~ x))$adj.r.squared, 3)}
#calculate rsq for variety + treatment
STATS <- DF %>%
group_by(Variety,Treatment) %>% 
summarise(Rsq=RSQ(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) %>%
# make a label
# one other option is to use stringr::str_wrap in geom_text
mutate(Label=paste("Treat",Treatment,", Rsq=",Rsq))

# set vertical position of rsq
VJUST = ifelse(STATS$Treatment=="A",1.5,3)
# finally the plot function
g + geom_text(data=STATS,aes(x=-Inf,y=+Inf,label=Label),
hjust = -0.1, vjust = VJUST,size=3)
```

For the last geom_text() call, I allowed the y coordinates of the text to be different by multiplying the Treatment.. You might need to adjust that depending on your plot..

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. It works very good, but it is still not possible to differ the r squared for the two treatments per variety. Could you just extend the STATS data frame with the treatment? At the end I would like to have 42 plots with two diefferent colored regression lines and dots with the two r squared values on each plot.

Comment: Oh ok, yes I get it now. Let me change the answer. And I was confused by the function you pasted. So 2 R^2 value per plot.

Comment: hi @David, I changed it to have only r^2.. If you want p-value then just add on to the summarize function..

Comment: I did it again with your new code but I get an error for the STATS data frame: > STATS <- sumfvvar %>%
+   group_by(treatment,Variety) %>% 
+   summarise(Rsq=RSQ(Fv.Fm,PARmolmsmean)) %>%
+   mutate(Label=paste("Treat",treatment,", Rsq=",Rsq))
Error in paste("Treat", treatment, ", Rsq=", Rsq) : 
  object 'treatment' not found                     I just changed the names...

Comment: ah I solved that. It was a problem with dplyr. I had that aready before...

Comment: dplyr clashes with something?

Comment: yeah I read allready something that dplyr and plyr had to be installed in a speciall order, otherwise it crashed...     How can I move the geom_text to another place? Just found that for geom_label

Comment: I used aes(x=-Inf,y=+Inf,..), this means left, top.. if you want it like left bottom it's -x=-Inf, y=-Inf and so on.. If you really want to be specific you need to give x and y coordinate.. or if say you want it near the line.. might need more coding

Comment: ok perfect.  Just one last question: Now the two r squared values are overlapped, I tried some combinations of hjust and vjust, but nothing changed. Any idea?

Comment: Did u use the as.numeric as I did? Hmm what kind of scales are on your y-axis

Comment: yes I did in the same way. all values are numeric and the values on the y axis are between 0 and 1

Comment: Ok see above, I manually added VJUST. You need to change the values 1.5 and 3 according to what are your y values. VJUST = ifelse(STATS$Treatment=="A",1.5,3)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example with the `ggpmisc` package:

```
library(ggpmisc)

set.seed(4321)
x <- 1:100
y <- (x + x^2 + x^3) + rnorm(length(x), mean = 0, sd = mean(x^3) / 4)
my.data <- data.frame(x = x, 
                      y = y,
                      group = c("A", "B"))
formula <- y ~ poly(x, 1, raw = TRUE)    
ggplot(my.data, aes(x, y)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ group) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = formula) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = formula, parse = TRUE, 
               mapping = aes(label = stat(rr.label)))
```

[image]