# Add R^2 value to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpmisc

I'm new to R.

I have produced the following plot but want to know how to include an R^2 value on the linear model line using ggpmisc and the `stat_poly_eq` function. The code I have is as follows -

```
ggplot(xray, aes(x=PercentGoodFish1g, y=PercentPopAff)) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm') +
  geom_point()
```

Can somebody help with this? I have visited links with examples but can't make sense of the code and what it is doing in order to apply it to my plot.

Thanks

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58835392/annotate-r-squared-to-ggplot-by-using-facet-wrap/58841957#58841957

Comment: @Harry H-W When new to R it is too easy to be unaware that most R functions are well documented. In this case the first example in the help page for stat_poly_eq() shows how to add R^2 to a plot. Checking the documentation is frequently the fastest way to solve a problem like this.